# Programms keep crashing and after a while laptop freezes or crashes

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, kernel, crash

Programs (Firefox, Chrome, gnome software) keep crashing randomly, ubuntu logs me out after a few minutes and after a few of these instances (about 5-10 minutes) laptop finally freezes or results in a black screen. "Intensive" processes like youtube seem to accelerate these occurences. Can't do any TTY or REIBUS to get out of t

Upon login, I get about 8 messages of apport errors, none of which help me.

At the start of this, I had a lot of kernel panic errors and couldn't even boot up again. Checked the hardware in recovery with fsck, it all seems fine. Upgraded everything but and still coulnd't log in because I had no space on my harddrive left. Cleaned that up, now about 50% free space. Now finally back up to the above problem, programs keep crashing and after a while, laptop freezes.

Hopefully unrelated: My screen display cracked (I think at the beginning of the week.(One week after warranty, ofc). Can still use a separate display, so graphics card should be fine.

ASUS X555U with Skylake. Ubuntu 16.04. Kernel is 4.4.21-040421-generic. Using proprietary NVIDIA 375.39 driver from nvidia-375.

Any advice/output I could use?

Edit: updated kernel to 4.10.9-041009-generic, no change.

Update: Tried installing from a live USB. Problem persists, keeps freezing after certain time, both installation and live CD. Could it be that this is just the live USB not vein proper or is my laptop a goner?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in a Ubuntu 16.04 with a GTX 1070. Solved it by erasing all traces of Nvidia drivers and going back to Nouveau.

If you need to use your GPU, try downgrading your drivers to a different version. 367 seems stable enough.

If that does not work, an extreme solution is to go back to Ubuntu 14.04. That's what I did on my laptop, as I need to use CUDA and CuDNN.

Refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics) for more details on how to reinstall your Nvidia drivers and subsequent errors that might appear on your computer.